# How do I create a single threaded queue using Tasks in .Net c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-queue

I have a service that monitors pushes database table changes.  I'm currently using a static backgroundworker to queue calls to the database.  To limit database SELECT calls, I'm dumping the queue each time the bgw is run. The queue really just tells the bgw to run again on completion if needed.

Is there a better way to achieve this with Task?

```
static Queue<int> _Queue = new Queue<int>();
static BackgroundWorker _bgw;

public RunTask()
{
    If (_bgw == null)
    {
        _bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

        _bgw.DoWork += (s,e) =>
            { //work}

        _bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,e) =>
        { 
            if (_Queue.Any())
            {
               _Queue.Clear();
               _bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

    }

    _Queue.Enqueue(1);

    if (!_bgw.IsBusy())
    {
       _Queue.Clear();
        _bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest to use `BlockingCollection` instead of Queue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks.  Some of the documentation I'm finding also suggests using a SemaphoreSlim with a size of 1.  Can you give me a brief code example of how my code above would work with a a BlockingCollection and Task?  Thanks in advance.